# JQuery UI Button Loaded On Ajax Not Styled

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, styling

So I have an ajax call that populates my dom with a button that I want to have the styling and functionality of JQuery UI's button elements, but when I call `$("button").button()` on my page being ready it doesn't style anything or give any of the expected functionality. Is there a way to dynamically load JQuery UI elements such as this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `$("button").button()` with your ajax complete, cause ajax in asynchronous. You can try like:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(html){
       $('button').button();
    }
});
```

As your ajax call populate dom with button so that you can also try:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(html){
       // html argument contains the dom element loaded via ajax
       $('button', html).button();
    }
});
```